# Strange assembly code for c alloca function with optimization disabled - gcc uses DIV and IMUL by a constant 16, and shifts?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, compiler-optimization, alloca

I have this simple code in c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <alloca.h>

int main()
{
    char* buffer = (char*)alloca(600);
    snprintf(buffer, 600, "Hello %d %d %d\n", 1, 2, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect that generated assembly code for alloca function would just decrement stack pointer(one sub instruction), and maybe do some alignments (one and instruction), but the resulting assembly code is very complicated and even more inefficient than you'd expect.

This is the output of `objdump -d main.o`, on the output of `gcc -c` (with no optimization, so the default `-O0`)

```
    0000000000400596 <main>:
  400596:   55                      push   %rbp
  400597:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40059a:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  40059e:   b8 10 00 00 00          mov    $0x10,%eax
  4005a3:   48 83 e8 01             sub    $0x1,%rax
  4005a7:   48 05 60 02 00 00       add    $0x260,%rax
  4005ad:   b9 10 00 00 00          mov    $0x10,%ecx
  4005b2:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edx
  4005b7:   48 f7 f1                div    %rcx
  4005ba:   48 6b c0 10             imul   $0x10,%rax,%rax
  4005be:   48 29 c4                sub    %rax,%rsp
  4005c1:   48 89 e0                mov    %rsp,%rax
  4005c4:   48 83 c0 0f             add    $0xf,%rax
  4005c8:   48 c1 e8 04             shr    $0x4,%rax
  4005cc:   48 c1 e0 04             shl    $0x4,%rax
  4005d0:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  4005d4:   48 8b 45 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  4005d8:   41 b9 03 00 00 00       mov    $0x3,%r9d
  4005de:   41 b8 02 00 00 00       mov    $0x2,%r8d
  4005e4:   b9 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%ecx
  4005e9:   ba a8 06 40 00          mov    $0x4006a8,%edx
  4005ee:   be 58 02 00 00          mov    $0x258,%esi
  4005f3:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  4005f6:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  4005fb:   e8 a0 fe ff ff          callq  4004a0 <snprintf@plt>
  400600:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400605:   c9                      leaveq 
  400606:   c3                      retq   
  400607:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40060e:   00 00
```

Any idea what is the aim of this generated assembly code? I'm using gcc 8.3.1.

Comment: Without optimization, gcc makes really terrible asm for `alloca`, rounding the allocation size to a multiple of 16 with `div` and `imul` instead of `and $-16, %reg`.

Comment: Did you turn of debug mode when compiling?

Comment: Why do you expect optimization without enabling optimization? ;)

Comment: Yes optimizations aren't enabled. But this seems like premature pessimization, even in debug mode, why not generate `and $-16, %reg`?

Comment: @klutt: True, but this goes beyond "not optimized": no sane person would *expect* GCC's canned sequence of instruction (or GIMPLE logic or whatever form it takes) for alloca logic to involve a `div` by compile-time-constant power of 2, instead of a shift or just an AND.  `x /= 16;` doesn't compile to a `div` if you write that yourself in C source, even with `gcc -O0`.

Comment: I guess you'll have to study the source code to find the answer

Comment: Sometimes compilers intentionally de-optimize the code to make it easier to follow in the debugger. The goal is to make it easier for the debugger (and user!) to understand, not necessarily perform better.

Comment: @tadman: true for `-O0` in general, but this is *not* an instance of that.  The majority of this is code for the single statement `char* buffer = alloca(600);`, and that asm is more complicated and verbose than it needs to be or than one would expect, which in itself makes it harder to understand than an obvious rounding idiom like `add $15, %reg` / `and $-16, %reg` / `sub %reg, %rsp`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is of course the usual debug-mode / anti-optimized behaviour of compiling each C statement to a separate block, with non-`register` variables actually in memory.  ([Why does clang produce inefficient asm with -O0 (for this simple floating point sum)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point)).

But yes, this goes beyond "not optimized".  No sane person would *expect* GCC's canned sequence of instructions (or GIMPLE or RTL logic, whatever stage it's expanded) for `alloca` logic to involve a `div` by compile-time-constant power of 2, instead of a shift or just an AND.  `x /= 16;` doesn't compile to a `div` if you write that yourself in C source, even with `gcc -O0`.

Normally GCC does compile-time evaluation of constant expressions as much as possible, like `x = 5 * 6` won't use imul at runtime.  But the point at which it expands its `alloca` logic must be after that point, probably pretty late (after most other passes) to explain all those missed optimizations.  So it doesn't benefit from the same passes that operate on your C source logic.

It's doing 2 things:

- **round the allocation size up** (a constant `600` after it puts that in a register) **to a multiple of 16** by doing: `((16ULL - 1) + x) / 16 * 16`.  A sane compiler would at least use right/left shift, if not optimize that to `(x+15) & -16`.  But unfortunately GCC uses `div` and `imul` by 16, even though it's a constant power of 2.
- **Round the final address of the allocated space to a multiple of 16** (even though it already was because RSP started 16-byte aligned and the allocation size was rounded up.)  It does this with `((p+15) >> 4) << 4` which is much more efficient than div/imul (especially for 64-bit operand-size on Intel before Ice Lake), but still less efficient than `and $-16, %rax`.  And of course silly to do work that was already pointless.

Then of course it has to store the pointer into `char* buffer`.

And in the block of asm for the next statement, reload it as an arg for `sprintf` (inefficiently into RAX instead of directly into RDI, typical for `gcc -O0`), along with setting up the register args.

---

**So this sucks a lot, but is very plausibly explained by late expansion of the canned logic for `alloca`, after most transformation ("optimization") passes have already run**.  Note that `-O0` [doesn't literally mean "no optimization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278757/disable-all-optimization-options-in-gcc/33284629#33284629), it just means "compile fast, and give consistent debugging".

---

Related:

- [How does gcc choose to number temporary variables from -fverbose-asm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62291561/how-does-gcc-choose-to-number-temporary-variables-from-fverbose-asm) - another discussion of that `-O0` alloca asm, with the same guess about expanding it late in GIMPLE passes, or even in RTL.  Also has **optimized asm for alloca / snprintf** which is vastly simpler.  In fact that's almost a duplicate; that question did also ask about the alloca code.
- [doing seemingly un-needed ops (crackme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194859/doing-seemingly-un-needed-ops-crackme/63195450#63195450) - I very lightly commented basically the same asm (for 32-bit mode), but mostly it's discussing hand-obfuscated asm.
- [How does GCC implement variable-length arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182307/how-does-gcc-implement-variable-length-arrays) shows the 32-bit version of this bad code, but doesn't comment on how much it sucks.